# Can I use duplicate detection to cancel a scheduled Azure service bus message?

Tags: c#, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm trying to come up with the best way to schedule a message for an Azure service bus queue or topic while leaving the option open for immediately sending a message instead of the scheduled message. I want to make sure I can protect myself against creating a duplicate message if I try to send the replacement message right at or after the scheduled time of the first message.

If you turn on duplicate detection and both messages have the same MessageId, does sending the second message prior to the scheduled enqueueing time of the first effectively cancel the scheduled message? Also, is it safe to assume that the second message will be ignored if the scheduled message is successfully queued first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you turn on duplicate detection and both messages have the same MessageId, does sending the second message prior to the scheduled enqueueing time of the first effectively cancel the scheduled message?

I do a test with the following sample code, and find that the second message will be ignored.

```
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        client.SendAsync(new BrokeredMessage("testmes1") { MessageId = "test1", ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(60) }).Wait();
    }
    else
    {
        client.SendAsync(new BrokeredMessage("testmes2") { MessageId = "test1" }).Wait();
    }

}
```

receive messages from the queue:

```
client.OnMessage(message =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Message body: {0}", message.GetBody<String>()));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Message id: {0}", message.MessageId));
});
```

output:

[image]

If you'd like to cancel a scheduled Message, you can try to call [CancelScheduledMessageAsync() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient?view=azureservicebus-4.1.1) before that scheduled Message becomes **active**.

```
client.CancelScheduledMessageAsync(sequenceNumber).Wait();
```

Comment: Based on your evidence, it's good to know that duplicate detection also checks scheduled messages for duplicates instead of only checking messages that have been enqueued in the past. I'm honestly a bit disappointed since my theoretical behavior would have allowed me to avoid having to store the sequence number of the scheduled message to cancel it later (instead I was going to use a MessageId that was unique to the business context of the message). Thanks for taking a look at this.